# What AWS services & workflows can I use to ingest and analyze JSON daily usage data from an API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, bigdata, analytics, data-science

I have some sample data (which is simulating real data that I will begin getting soon), that represents user behavior on a website.

The data is broken down into 2 json files for every day of usage.  (When I'm getting the real data, I will want to fetch it every day at midnight). At the bottom of this question are example snippets of what this data looks like, if that helps.

I'm no data scientist, but I'd like to be able to do some basic analysis on this data.  I want to be able to see things like how many of the user-generated objects existed on any given day, and the distribution of different attributes that they have/had.  I'd also like to be able to visualize which objects are getting edited more, by whom, when and how frequently.  That sort of thing.

I think I'd like to be able to make dashboards in google data studio (or similar), which basically means that I get this data in a usable format into a normal relational database.  I'm thinking postgres in aws RDS (there isn't *that* much data that I need something like aurora, I think, though I'm not terribly opposed).

I want to automate the ingestion of the data (for now the sample data sets I have stored on S3, but eventually from an API that can be called daily). And I want to automate any reformatting/processing this data needs to get the types of insights I want.

AWS has so many data science/big data tools that it feels to me like there should be a way to automate this type of data pipeline, but the terminology and concepts are too foreign to me, and I can't figure out what direction to move in.

Thanks in advance for any advice that y'all can give.

---

Data example/description:

One file is catalog of all user generated objects that exist at the time the data was pulled, along with their attributes.  It looks something like this:

```
{
  "obj_001": {
    "id": "obj_001",
    "attr_a": "a1",
    "more_attrs": {
      "foo": "fred":,
      "bar": null
    }
  },
  "obj_002": {
    "id": "obj_002",
    "attr_a": "b2",
    "more_attrs": {
      "foo": null,
      "bar": "baz"
    }
  }
}
```

The other file is an array that lists all the user edits to those objects that occurred in the past day, which resulted in the state from the first file.  It looks something like this:

```
[
  { 
    "edit_seq": 1,
    "obj_id": "obj_002",
    "user_id": "u56",
    "edit_date": "2020-01-27",
    "times": {
      "foo": null,
      "bar": "baz"
    }
  },
  { 
    "edit_seq": 2,
    "obj_id": "obj_001",
    "user_id": "u25",
    "edit_date": "2020-01-27",
    "times": {
      "foo": "fred",
      "bar": null
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the architecture that you want to deploy. If you want event based trigger, I would use SQS, I have used it heavily, as soon as someone drop a file in s3 it can trigger the SQS which can be used to trigger Lambda.

Here is a link which can give you some idea: http://blog.zenof.ai/processing-high-volume-big-data-concurrently-with-no-duplicates-using-aws-sqs/

Answer (score 0):

You could build Data Pipelines using AWS DataPipeline. For e.g. if you want to read data from S3 and some transformations and then to Redshift.

You can also have look on AWS Glue, which has Spark backend, which can also crawler the schema and perform ETL.